# Shopping cart displays records twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

problem is that when the same item is added to the cart again then it display the same record of the same product twice, here i want that when i press add to cart button twice or three time then it should be increment quantity of the same item.

```
protected void AddToCartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    book_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["book_id"].ToString());
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Book where book_id = " + book_id + "";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {                 
        //book_id =Convert.ToInt32(dr["book_id"]);
        title = dr["title"].ToString();
        //quantity = dr["quantity"].ToString();
        quantity = QuantityTxt.Text;
        price = dr["price"].ToString();
    }
    //Restrict User to enter some quantity that he wants...
    if(Convert.ToInt32(QuantityTxt.Text)>Convert.ToInt32(quantity))
    {
        ErrorMsglbl.Text = "Please Enter Lower Quantity";
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMsglbl.Text = "";
    }
    // Creating Cookies to store the value and then i will assign to data table... 

    if (Request.Cookies["ShoppingCart"] == null)
    {
        Response.Cookies["ShoppingCart"].Value = book_id.ToString() + "," + title.ToString() + "," + quantity.ToString() + "," + price.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["ShoppingCart"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Cookies["ShoppingCart"].Value = Request.Cookies["ShoppingCart"].Value + "|" + book_id.ToString() + "," + title.ToString() + "," + quantity.ToString() + "," + price.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["ShoppingCart"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
    }

    Response.Redirect("BookDetails.aspx?book_id="+book_id.ToString()+"&Cat_ID="+ViewState["cat"]+"");

}// End Add To Cart Button...
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem lies in else block

```
 Response.Cookies["ShoppingCart"].Value = Request.Cookies["ShoppingCart"].Value + 
"|" + book_id.ToString() + "," + title.ToString() + 
"," + quantity.ToString() + "," + price.ToString();
```

Here you are assigning previous cookie value to a new cookie along with new content. For e.g. if you have  "1, Shoe, 1,25" in your cookie and add same product into cart again you will get something like "1, Shoe, 1,25| 1,Shoe, 1,25".

This problem can be solved by multiple approaches

1. Split your cookies and check book_id value
2. Use object to store cart item and save them in session.

Approach First

```
String[] carts = Request.Cookies["ShoppingCart"].Value.Split("|")
bool bookIdExists = false;
foreach(string cartDetail in carts)
{
  string  bookId = cartDetail.Split(",")[0];
  if(bookId == newBookId)
  {
    bookIdExists = true;
  }
}
if(!bookIDExists)
{
  //Add your new item to Cookie
}
```

Second Approach

```
public Class Cart
{
  public int BookId {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public int Qty {get; set;}
  public decimal Price {get; set}
}

List<Cart> carts =Session["Cart"]==null? new List<Cart>(): Session["Cart"] as List<Cart>;
var existingCart = carts.Where(x=> x.BookId==newBookId).FirstOrDefault();
if(existingCart==null)
{
  Cart c= new Cart {
  BookId = newBookId,
  Title =newTitle,
  Qty = newQty,
  Price =newPrice
};
 carts.Add(c);
 Session["Cart"] = carts;
}
```

You may come with better approach to solve the problem.

> But it is terrible idea to use cookie to store your cart details.

Comment: thanks for answering, your suggestion give me the right way to solve but i cannot solve the problem yet.